# Error "for pooled tables cluster tables and projection views join is not allowed: "T588B""

Tags: abap

I'm new to ABAP Development, trying to join T588B and T588T and got this error "for pooled tables cluster tables and projection views join is not allowed: "T588B"".

```
SELECT a~mandt AS mandt a~userg AS userg a~mntyp AS mntyp a~menue AS menue
a~infty AS infty b~sprsl AS sprsl b~dtext As dtext
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE zfinaltable
  FROM T588B AS a LEFT JOIN T588T AS b ON a~mntyp = b~mntyp
  WHERE a~mntyp = 'I'
```

I just wanted to join the two table and store the output data into `zfinaltable` table which is custom table.

Any idea on how to accomplish this join? An example would be really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation: "Pooled and cluster tables cannot be joined using join expressions."

http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abapselect_join.htm

You need to use a for all entries select instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `SELECT. ... ENDSELECT.` for selecting the data from table `T588B` and inside of it reading the data from `T588T`. An example could look like this. I think it could be easily adapted to your needs.

```
DATA: ls_T588B TYPE T588B.
DATA: lt_T588T TYPE TABLE OF T588T.

SELECT mntyp menue
  FROM T588B
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF ls_t588b.
  SELECT *
    FROM T588T
    APPENDING TABLE lt_T588T
    WHERE MNTYP = ls_t588b-mntyp
      AND MENUE = ls_t588b-menue.
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: Thanks! used internal table and loaded the data required in the join and then looped through the internal tables finally delivering the output for the function module.
 
I really wanted to avoid the loop but seems like I had to go through the  pain of looping the tables.

Comment: Happy to have helped! Do not forget to upvote and accept the answer. :)