# Using the table BSEG in a selection without INNER JOIN

Tags: abap, sap-erp, opensql

I am trying to do a selection of the field `KOART` from the table `BSEG`, by using the below code:

```
CONSTANTS: lc_d TYPE c VALUE 'D'.
    SELECT k~bukrs,
         k~belnr,
         k~budat,
         k~gjahr,
         k~buzei,
         k~kunnr,
         i~banks,
         i~bankl,
         i~bankn
    FROM bsid AS k
    INNER JOIN knbk AS i ON k~kunnr EQ i~kunnr
*    INNER JOIN bseg
    INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_data_knbk)
    WHERE k~bukrs IN @so_bukrs
    AND k~budat IN @so_budat
    AND k~blart IN @so_blart
*    AND bseg~koart = @lc_d.
```

Normally I would have put the Inner join syntax for the table, but being that `bseg` is a cluster table, it does not accept the inner join option, and thus I cannot use the field `koart`.

May anyone know, how can I put the field `KOART` of the BSEG in the selection above?

Thank you very much in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As explained by József Szikszai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69347303/1620671), an inner join is not actually necessary in this particular use-case, because the table BSID contains only customer documents anyway.

But if it *were* necessary here, then you would have two options:

The first would be to switch to SAP HANA as database backend, because then all the cluster tables will be converted to regular tables. You won't get around this in the long-term due to SAP announcing that they will be charging extra for supporting other databases from 2027 and drop support for non-HANA in 2030 completely. But due to the cost and planning effort involved in a HANA conversion, this is likely not a serious option if you are facing this problem *today*.

When you need a temporary solution until your inevitable HANA conversion, then there is a second option. You can solve this problem using a second select with a `FOR ALL ENTRIES` condition.

```
SELECT bukrs,
     belnr,
     budat,
     gjahr,
     buzei,
     kunnr,
  FROM bsid     
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_data_bsid)
  WHERE bukrs IN @so_bukrs
  AND budat IN @so_budat
  AND blart IN @so_blart.

IF lt_data_bsid IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT bukrs,
         belnr,
         gjahr,
         buzei
    FROM bseg
    INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_bseg)
    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_data_bsid
    WHERE bukrs = @lt_data_bsid-bukrs
      AND belnr = @lt_data_bsid-belnr
      AND gjahr = @lt_data_bsid-gjahr
      AND buzei = @lt_data_bsid-buzei
      AND koart = @lc_d.
         
ENDIF.
```

Note that this approach has a number of problems:

- You now have the data in two internal tables instead of one, so you might have to perform a couple `READ TABLE`'s or `LOOP AT... WHERE`'s to puzzle the data together.
- Two SELECTs instead of one mean two network roundtrips to the database server instead of one. You also miss out on most internal optimizations your database might be able to do for JOINs. Which increases the runtime of your program.
- The first SELECT might return a ton of data you don't need, so you might run into memory problems. You can solve that by using a database cursor (`OPEN CURSOR`) and `FETCH` the results in packets. But that will degrade performance even further.
- Never forget the `IF itab1 IS NOT INITIAL` check when using `FOR ALL ENTRIES`. Intuitively, one would assume to receive no database rows at all if the lookup table is empty. But what actually will happen is that the `WHERE` conditions which mention the `FOR ALL ENTRIES` table get ignored completely and you receive **all** the table rows with `koart = 'D'`.

But if you have to do a JOIN with a cluster-table, then there is unfortunately no other option.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need KOART for this selection. `KOART EQ 'D'` means customer postings, but BSID contains customer postings only (see the third field of the table is the customer number).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I need the KOART in order to check whether a client has the value 'D' or Debitoren. It is in my requirements.

Comment: There are only customers (Debitoren) in table BSID, you don't need to worry about that. On the other hand there are only customer bank accounts in table KNBK, so you are double protected.